# Logo doesn't float left in header?

Tags: css

I am trying to float my logo to the left in the header but it doesn't float to left at all. I would really appreciate if someone could point our my error since I am new to CSS.

This is my website if you would like to see my problem live: http://cashski.com/

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="center_navigation">
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        <a href="buy-instagram-followers.php">Instagram Followers</a>
        <a href="buy-instagram-photo-likes.php">Instagram Photo Likes</a>
        <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Optima, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#navigation{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #2d5b89;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #244a75;
}
.center_navigation {
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:0px auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.center_navigation a {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4px;
    color: #babcc5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.center_navigation a:hover {
    color: white;
}
.center_navigation a img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Here's your problem: `.center_navigation a { float: right; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your all `anchor` tags are `float:right` and your image is inside a `anchor` tag, so making img `float:left` doesn't change much.

So you either need to put the style on the container of image ie. anchor tag like this

```
<a href="index.php" style="float: left;">
   <img src="img/logo.png">
</a>
```

or if your image is always in last anchor tag then you can also use this

```
.center_navigation a:last-child{
    float: left;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P6YJV/)